# How do I create an object with callback methods on it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to create an object with "callback" type functions that work like the functions on a websocket.  I cannot for the life of me figure out the right language for what I should be googling to figure this out.

If I create a websocket, it might look like this

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://myUrl");

ws.onopen = function() {
    // Do things with open socket
}

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    // Do things with e
}

ws.onclose = function() {
    // Do things with closed socket
}
```

Simple, easy to use, very straightforward.

I want to create my own object/class.  We'll call it FancyWebSocket.  What would the backend of FancyWebSocket need to look like in order to have onopen and onmessage work correctly?  I need it to work *exactly* like a WebSocket works, because I will be passing either FancyWebSocket or WebSocket to another object, and that other object needs to interact with both of them the same.

Sorry this feels like it should be simple and I'm just going crazy trying to find it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to extend/inherit from the WebSocket and create your own class/function constructor,  see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

Comment: I don't actually want any of the original WebSocket behavior though.  To decrease confusion here I called it a FancyWebSocket, but it's actually just an entirely different communication method.  So at runtime I'll be able to pass either a WebSocket or my other  custom object to my main code, and that main code will do what it does not caring what the actually communication method is.

Comment: A websocket is an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm testing right now that I think works?  It looks like I just define the function signature as an empty function inside the class, then when I create the object I can declare that same signature as another function and it overwrites the original one internal to the class and works.

I think this works, posting it as an answer and hoping either I'm right or someone will come along and explain why I'm still wrong.

```
class FancySocket {
    constructor(port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    connect() {
        console.log(`Connecting to ${this.port}`);
        this.onopen();
    }

    onopen = function () {};
}

var fancySocket = new FancySocket(42);

fancySocket.onopen = function () {
    console.log('Socket Opened');
};

fancySocket.connect();
```

Outputs

```
Connecting to 42
Socket Opened
```